# a conflict when using zero-width-space and execCommand("copy")

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'll try to make this as simple as possible to explain what I mean. 
I want to show a popup to a user with an url link to copy (dynamically created), in example (in real the text is much longer):

```
var url = "http://myweb.com/en/​728,​1,​5a2a16,​5e4f4f,​4a3f7a,​12,​12";
```

and to show this correctly (I mean to break this line nicely to fit the popup window) I use zero-width-space `&#8203;` so the code would look like this:

```
var url = "http://myweb.com/en/​728,&#8203;​1,&#8203;​5a2a16,​&#8203;5e4f4f,​&#8203;4a3f7a,​&#8203;12,​&#8203;12";
$("#content").html(url);
```

Next, when the popup appears I can copy this text by selecting everything and use ctrl+c or just click a button to auto-copy which I use for that a piece of google code:

```
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
var seltext = document.querySelector("#content");  
var range = document.createRange();  
range.selectNode(seltext);  
window.getSelection().addRange(range);  
var successful = document.execCommand("copy");
```

The problem begins after I copy the URL (doesn't matter which way) and paste it into the browser and hit enter, after that I get this:

```
The requested URL myweb.com/en/728,â€‹1,â€‹5a2a16,â€‹5e4f4f,â€‹4a3f7a,â€‹12,â€‹12,â€‹12 was not found on this server.
```

The problem disappears when I remove zero-width-space character and use  `$("#content").text(url);` (text instead of html) but then I get another problem with correct long line breaking. Anybody has an idea how to make these things work together? (so the line will break in areas where I want - after commas and copy function will not copy any extra characters, only this what the user see on the screen)

Comment: See this article: http://dtidatarecovery.com/stripping-nonsense-characters-in-urls-with-apache-mod_rewrite/

Comment: This article could be interesting, but I can't make it work in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best solution is to just use CSS for that.
Note that in Firefox&IE you must set the anchor's display attribute to `block`, otherwise you will not be able to break the words.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test 1</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            a { word-break: break-all; width: 150px; display: block;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="http://www">http://www.domain.com/TherearemanyvariationsofpassagesofLoremIpsumavailable,butthemajorityhavesufferedalterationinsomeform,byinjectedhumour,orrandomisedwordswhichdon'tlookevenslightlybelievable.IfyouaregoingtouseapassageofLoremIpsum,youneedtobesurethereisn'tanythingembarrassinghiddeninthemiddleoftext.AlltheLoremIpsumgeneratorsontheInternettendtorepeatpredefinedchunksasnecessary,makingthisthefirsttruegeneratorontheInternet.Itusesadictionaryofover200Latinwords,combinedwithahandfulofmodelsentencestructures,togenerateLoremIpsumwhichlooksreasonable.ThegeneratedLoremIpsumisthereforealwaysfreefromrepetition,injectedhumour,ornoncharacteristicwordsetc</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

This approach will give you the solution for both the <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> and the `execCommand("copy")`, since the url wasn't really changed.

If you cannot use this approach - you should remove the white-space chars from your string before calling the `execCommand` to make sure you copy the stripped-string.

If you really want the execCommand (and not the CSS version) here is the code you can use:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Test 2</title>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <style type="text/css">
                a { word-break: break-all; width: 150px; display: block;}
                .hidden {font-size:1px; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: -100000px; top: -10000px;}
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var preventDoubleCall = false;
            function copyWrapper() {
                if (preventDoubleCall) {
                    preventDoubleCall = false;
                    return;
                }
                $('.hidden').text($('a').text().replace(/,/g, "This is the text to replace"))
                window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
                var seltext = $(".hidden")[0];
                var range = document.createRange();
                range.selectNode(seltext);
                window.getSelection().addRange(range);
                preventDoubleCall = true;
                var successful = document.execCommand("copy");
            }
            $(function(){
                $(document).bind('copy', function() {
                    copyWrapper();
                });
                $('#click-to-copy').click(function() {
                    copyWrapper();
                });
            });
            </script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <a href="http://www">http://www.domain.com/TherearemanyvariationsofpassagesofLoremIpsumavailable,butthemajorityhavesufferedalterationinsomeform,byinjectedhumour,orrandomisedwordswhichdon'tlookevenslightlybelievable.IfyouaregoingtouseapassageofLoremIpsum,youneedtobesurethereisn'tanythingembarrassinghiddeninthemiddleoftext.AlltheLoremIpsumgeneratorsontheInternettendtorepeatpredefinedchunksasnecessary,makingthisthefirsttruegeneratorontheInternet.Itusesadictionaryofover200Latinwords,combinedwithahandfulofmodelsentencestructures,togenerateLoremIpsumwhichlooksreasonable.ThegeneratedLoremIpsumisthereforealwaysfreefromrepetition,injectedhumour,ornoncharacteristicwordsetc</a>
            <div class="hidden"></div>
            <button id="click-to-copy">Click here to copy</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

You should change the replace line with the text you would like to replace (the line-break/commas/etc). 
I had to use the "out of view" method, because you cannot copy text on a hidden elements. 
The code will copy the text that you want regardless of which part you selected. If you want to can change it so the text will take only the original part that you selected (and not all the text inside the anchor).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's better now with your solution but I would prefer to break the line after commas. I wounder how would work the second approach (removing white-space before calling execCommand). The only way I can think is to get the content, remove white-space, send back the content and finally run the coping code which I showed above but I don't like this idea. Maybe there is better one, but for now I will use your suggestion with css.

Comment: Check the answer, I added a JS code that covers what you asked for

Comment: Thank you, but I think I'll stick to the just CSS solution (at least for now)